# check if date appear in a table, and if so print some table SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, if-statement

in need to check if today appear in some dates table
and if so, to print a table (in a job running every day)
**i must use IF.**

here is what i try - but it is not working: because in table time there is more then 1 value. i also try use EXISTS but it doesn't work too.

```
IF GETDATE()  = (
select date
from Time 
where day_by_OF = 2
)

 
begin 
exec sp_run_update;
end
```

Comment: OK, I learned something. i am using SQL Server

Comment: What does this mean: "print a table" ?

Comment: i will update my quotation. i need to run a procedure if the condition is correct

Comment: So if today appears in any date where day_by_OF = 2 then you execute ?

Comment: yes, if day_by_OF = 2 then you execut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly this will be ok:

```
IF ( select count(*)
     from Time 
     where day_by_OF = 2 
     and date = GETDATE())  > 0
begin                  
    select * from time;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from how to write procedural stuff in sql-server, it is better to let the database apply your search criteria:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Time WHERE convert(date,date) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
```

Can it be it is not working because `GETDATE()` returns datetime value and not a date.

[More Info on GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

this is working:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT date FROM time 
WHERE day_by_OF = 2
 and convert(date,date) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
```

thanks U all